# Magento 1 end of life - where can I download Magento 1.5.1 patch to run PHP 5.4?

Tags: patches, php-5.4, magento-1.5

Magento has just removed all support to 1.* as it reached end of life. I need to create an tests environment like my client that uses 1.5.1. I understand that it is way too old but it is his choice to use old versions.

Anyone knows where can I get the patch to make Magento 1.5.1 work with PHP 5.4 ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Magento has removed the official links but there is a project on github where all releases of magento can be found.

The link is https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/releases

Currently the archives of Magento 1 are still available on [Magento Tech Resources](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download) and you can download the archives in there.

[image]

The patch can be found on this URL as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Hey sure I have seen that but theses packages do not include the patches for PHP 5.4. Can you help me with the patch ?

Comment: not quite sure if there are patches for php 5.4 but the list of patches is there too
https://i.imgur.com/I9oiZCR.png

Comment: also i saw the support for 5.4 is there https://i.imgur.com/ZSk1ew7.png

Comment: Great I will check that ! Thank you ! I will add this info to your response and give it a positive. Thanks !!!

Comment: It looks like it was taken down, other ideas ?

Comment: Updated my answer. there is a project on github that has all releases

Comment: Cool that's great !!! Thank you !!

Answer (score 4):

Check github repo from OpenMage – https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/releases. It contain releases starting from 1.1.1 up to 1.9.4.5.

Security patches can be found in Magento patches mirror repository – https://github.com/akai-z/magento1-open-source-patches